# Built-in mic not plugged in? (Windows)

Tags: windows, windows-10, audio, microphone

Here is a picture of the current status of my microphone:

[image: microphone panel]

I'm confused as to how a built-in microphone could be unplugged. I went online and found some similar problems and tried all of the suggested solutions, but none of them seemed to work. Does anyone know the solution to this problem?

Comment: Look in Device Manager and see if the Microphone has a red or yellow mark. If so, it may have a hardware error. If not try right clicking and installing or updating the driver.

Comment: Could be 2 things. Either you have both a build-in mic for your webcam and a line-in / mic-in connector, and this Microphone is referreing to the mic-in. Or second, you have a pricacy switch for the webcam, and given that the build-in mic is for your webcam, disabling the webcam also disables the microphone. See if you have such switch and enable the webcam. Most likely the mic will also get activated again. This is a physical switch that literally disconnects the mic and webcam.

Comment: @John The device actually doesn't even show in Device Manager. That's why most of the solutions I found online don't work.

Comment: A privacy switch would definitely do this. It can be the latch before the webcam's lens, or it is a physical switch, usually on the side of the laptop. It could be drivers missing, but then device manager would show you unknown devices, as @john asked you to look for.

Comment: I looked at the Microphone on my computers here. The microphone device may be in the Audio section, not on its own.